# Centering QMainWindow is off center how can I solve this?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I am using a QMainWindow which has a QWidget set as its central widget I am using this code to center the screen currently.

```
class WindowMain(QMainWindow):
# set up the the window
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.resize(1250, 1000)  # size of the window
    self.mainGameWidget = MainGameWidget()  # create the main game widget
    menuBar = self.menuBar()  # menuBar
    self.initUI()  # set up the main window UI

def initUI(self):
    self.setCentralWidget(self.mainGameWidget)  # set the central widget of MainWindow to the game widget
    self.center()

def center(self):
    qr = self.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    self.move(qr.topLeft())


class MainGameWidget(QWidget):  # Main game widget added to the main window
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    ' Main layout of this widget along with its tabs '
    self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.buttons = QGridLayout()  # buttons to control game
    self.tabs = QTabWidget()
    self.tab1 = QWidget()
    self.tab2 = QWidget()
    self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Stats")
    self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Table")
    self.tab1_layout = QGridLayout()  # layout for the first tab

    ' setting up the team grid layout '
    self.team_grid = QGridLayout()
    self.team_grid.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

    # add the tabs to the main layout of this widget so they are displayed
    # this widget will be the central widget for the main game
    self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
    self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
    self.initUI()

    self.home_box.setMaximumWidth(800)
    self.stats_box.setMaximumWidth(800)
    self.away_box.setMaximumWidth(800)
    self.user_box.setMaximumWidth(800)
```

The centering is a bit off and I have searched online and tried out a few different suggestions I but they all yield the same result. I am using a widescreen display (2560, 1080)and I'm not sure if this has something to do with it?

[image]

Comment: Off *how*? Vertically? Horizontally? How much? On what OS? Also, be aware that QDesktopWidget is considered obsolete, use [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) instead.

Comment: My OS is Windows and sorry the explanation was a bit vague it is off to the left a small bit its just not center. When I remove the center method it opens on the left hand side of the screen.

Comment: Do you have some toolbars or "widgets" on the sides of the screen? Can you provide an accurate and full screen shot of the result? Also, try with QScreen, and don't use `availableGeometry()` but the *full* `geometry()`.

Comment: Does the `MainGameWidget` have a minimum size set? Please provide a [mre] (including that widget). Also please add comments as notifications of your edits, we cannot follow all posts.

Comment: This is what it looks like when the GUI opens, no I dont have any widgets on the sides but I do have a dialog which opens first before the QMainWindow to prompt for the users for their details

Comment: Sorry, that code is *not* reproducible (there are missing functions and attributes). It must be some code we can copy, paste and run, possibly without any substantial modification. Also, ensure that the indentation is correct (read how to properly [format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)) by checking the post preview.

Comment: It should be easy to check whether it calculates the position and center correctly by printing the coordinates and geometries in each of the calculation steps. Then you will quickly find which step is wrong. Btw. is the frame geometry correct? Isn't it set only after resize event is processed? (I do not know, I am just guessing)

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager depending on the OS, the frame geometry is reliable or guessed (X11). On Windows it should be correct, and if the window has not been shown yet it can only reflect an *explicit* `resize()` or `setGeometry()` (otherwise it defaults to 640x480, not considering size constraints). The problem is: if a child widget is added and that widget has minimum size requirements, it will invalidate the `center()`, as at that moment the layout has not been activated yet, so the frame geometry is still based on the previous call to `resize()`.